# Non-magic non-stabilizer multi-qubit states

Tags: stabilizer-state, magic-states, wigner-function

Does anyone know of any resources that show examples of simple multi-qubit states which are non-stabilizer states but that are still classically efficiently stimulable? Another way to phrase it is that I am looking for examples of multi-qubit states that fall under the green section of the Venn diagram at minute 58 in this lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0G2nC-FyWec (note the part which says "positive wigner representation" on the slide is only applicable to odd-dimensioned qudit states, so please ignore that for the purposes of this question :)).

Thank you!